# Android MediaCodec playing 1080p but choppy 2k,4k

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

I have created a video decoding module in C++ MediaCodec API without using the AMediaExtractor. While it can decode perfectly decode 1080p video, it has problems decoding 2k and 4k video. Other players eg. MX Player plays it perfectly. The 4k video is clear but choppy, tested using OnePlus 3.

I get several AMEDIACODEC_INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER  as well as cannot dequeue some input buffers.

I have found this https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/886. It states that the video level is above the current minimum. But how can MX Player play it then?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Arauf, Found anything ?